# How can I run these macros together across every worksheet in the workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have made an excel book, where a data set is pasted into one tab, and macros are run to filter out the information into seperate worksheets, ready to batch PDF. Currently I have a button on each sheet to 'Update Table' and have to go through each sheet to click this button. I want this as one button on the first sheet. I also have a button to set the print area on all sheets - this one loops and works fine. I'd like to merge the codes, so one button will go through each sheet to update the tables, and then set the print area.

I have tried merging these codes together with no luck so far despite hours of googling, so thought I'd try here. I'm very new to VBA (just been teaching myself for a few weeks).

```
    Sub Auto_Table_Update()

        Sheets("All Data").Range("A50:K9999").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CriteriaRange:=Range("C2:C3"), CopyToRange:=Range("A5:K9999"), Unique:= _
            False
    '*Advance Filter Macro to update the table in the worksheet*


        Range("C4").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(R[-1]C,3)"
        Range("C5").Select
    '*Sets the worksheet name as the first 3 letters in cell C4*

    End Sub


    Sub Workbook_Print_Area()
    Dim ws      As Worksheet

    Dim LR      As Long, _
        LC      As Long

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            LC = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC)).Address
            End With
    ' *sets the print area on every sheet*
    Next ws
    End Sub
```

Like I said, I just want one button to run the above codes on every sheet. Or at least the 'Auto_Update_Table' to be run on every sheet rather than having a button to run it on each sheet like I currently do.

I appreciate some of it will be badly coded.. Any explanations of the changes would be much appreciated too. I appreciate your patience.. I am trying to get my head around all this :)

UPDATE

I have tried doing this:

```
    Sub One_Button()
    Dim ws      As Worksheet

    Dim LR      As Long, _
        LC      As Long

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        With ws
            Sheets("All Data").Range("A50:K9999").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CriteriaRange:=Range("C2:C3"), CopyToRange:=Range("A5:K9999"), Unique:= _
                False

            Range("C4").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(R[-1]C,3)"
            Range("C5").Select
            LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            LC = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC)).Address
            End With
    Next ws
    End Sub
```

This gives me the error 'The extract range has a missing or invalid field name.' Is this because it is trying to run on the first worksheet (with the main data set)? If so, how do I tell it to ignore the main data set sheet?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Seems like you're almost there. This is the loop through your sheets `For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` so just add your filter code inside it referencing `ws` instead of hard-coding the sheet name.

Comment: thanks @SJR for the quick response. not entirely sure what you mean 'instead of hard-coding the sheet name'. the only time I name the sheet in the filter code is to reference the main data set, as this is where i need to grab the data from. i can't replace this with a ws can I? check out my update above. thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: Not quite clear what you're doing. Do you want to loop through every sheet and filter `Sheets("All Data").Range("A50:K9999")` each time? Which sheet are the criteria on, and where is the copytorange?

Comment: Yes. The main data sheet creates a list of unique companies (using formulas). The criteria on the seperate sheets are taken from that list (so I essentially get a sheet for each company name). Then the advanced filter pulls out each instance of that company in the data set, and copies all the data in those rows into a blank table on the sheet. So ultimately I have all the data relating to each seperate company on each seperate sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this? You need to make sure your criteria range includes the correct headers and doesn't have any spaces.

```
Sub One_Button()

Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim LR      As Long, _
    LC      As Long

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "All Data" Then
        With ws
            Sheets("All Data").Range("A50:K9999").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                     CriteriaRange:=ws.Range("C2:C3"), CopyToRange:=ws.Range("A5"), Unique:=False
            ws.Range("C4").FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(R[-1]C,3)"
            LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            LC = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC)).Address
        End With
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: It gives me a 'Subscript out of range' error. Highlighting this part on the debug:

       'Sheets("All_Data").Range("A50:K9999").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                             CriteriaRange:=ws.Range("C2:C3"), CopyToRange:=ws.Range("A5"), Unique:=False'

Comment: I think it works now. Just had to change the 'CopyToRange:=ws.Range("A5")' to 'ws.Range("A5:K9999"). THANK YOU!! :D